# Scrapy - Get or flush stats while spider is running

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Is there a way to flush the stats (scraped pages/items) of a *currently running* crawl? I'm running a very long crawl, and occasionally the stats so far will come up, but then are quickly pushed away by more information. I'd like to check on these stats periodically if possible - so I know roughly how much longer it will take or if I should finish it prematurely.

And as a subquestion of that - is there a way to kill the spider such that what's been crawled so far will still output to the designated output file? (-o flag)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to look into writing your own [Extension](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.24/topics/extensions.html#writing-your-own-extension) ? You could look at the [Stats Collector documentation](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.24/topics/stats.html) too for how to get stats

Answer (score 2):

As @kiran.koduru mentioned, you can use an extension along with `twisted`'s `LoopingCall` class to persist the stats on a given interval.

For example:

```
from scrapy import signals
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall


class PersistStats(object):
    """An extension to persist stats on a given interval.

    Settings
    --------
    PERSIST_STATS_INTERVAL : integer (default: 60)
         Interval in seconds.

    """

    def __init__(self, interval):
        self.interval = interval
        self.tasks = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        obj = cls(crawler.settings.getint('PERSIST_STATS_INTERVAL', 60))
        crawler.signals.connect(obj.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(obj.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return obj

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        task = self.tasks[spider.name] = LoopingCall(self.perist_stats, spider)
        task.start(self.interval)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        task = self.tasks.pop(spider.name)
        task.stop()

    def perist_stats(self, spider):
        # TODO: store stats somewhere.
        data = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()
        spider.logger.info("Persisting stats:\n%s", data)
```

On your second question, if you kill the spider gracefully (one <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), it should store the file correctly. Otherwise you would need to either provide your own feed exporter or an extension to write items directly to the target file instead of buffering in a temporary file.